# NSIS MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN

Tags: nsis

I don't understand why:

If I use

```
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN notepad.exe
```

it works, Notepad starts.

If I use

```
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN winword.exe
```

nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad is in the Windows directory and that directory is searched by `Exec`. Winword is in some subfolder under program files most likely (and not a part of %path%) and therefore it is not found.

The best solution is to provide the full path to the application you want to run.

Normally you do

```
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN "$InstDir\MyApp.exe"
```

You could try

```
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_FUNCTION myrun
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

Function myrun
ExecShell "" "winword.exe"
FunctionEnd
```

This will work if Word registers itself in the App Paths key. Alternatively you could `ExecShell` a .Doc file if you know Word is installed.

Comment: in the windows execute window both works, notepad.exe and winword.exe.

Comment: If you are talking about the run dialog, it uses the same function as ExecShell so try the 2nd code example I posted.